# TeXlipse hotkeys for bold, italic, underlined

Tags: bold, italic, text-decorations, texlipse

Are there any hotkeys to make a text bold or italic in TeXlipse plug-in? It is tiresome to type `\textbf{}` and `\textit{}` each time I need to emphasize some word. Most of other TeX-editors support standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>" and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, but in TeXlipse it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `CTRL`+`space`?

Comment: That's it, thanks! Can you put it as an answer? So that I accept it, and you'll get reputation.

Comment: Side remark: You should emphasize with `\emph{}`, which is semantically better and also nests correctly.

Comment: @Delynx: If you use the @name syntax than the person you are writing to will get notified about your message.

Comment: @ipavlic: please add your comment as an answer as it seems to solve the problem.

Comment: @Delynx: Would you be so kind to give the exact keystroke sequence (also, are there shorthands like `b`,`Ctrl`+`space`). That would make my answer more useful. I don't have Eclipse at hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeXlipse has an auto-complete feature which you can access with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.