# Style Completion in Texlipse not working

Tags: auto-completion, texlipse

Though TeXlipse is a great tex editor, one complaint I have is the lack of hot keys for common  style formatting for characters such as bold italic. I found the preference of TeXlipse has an page on style completion which seems to deal with the problem. My understanding of the usage of this feature is:

1. select a word
2. Press Ctrl+space (on windows, the key is Ctrl+Alt+space)
3. A window pops up and I can choose the format style listed in the style completion page in the preference.

However when I hit the enter to choose a format style, nothing happens? It seems that Eclipse ignores my action. Does anyone encounter this problem? And what is the alternative way to fast
format characters using TeXlipse?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you still have the issue, please send a bug report to [TeXlipse](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=133306&atid=726818). Thank you in advance.
2. On Windows the smart key is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.
3. The knowledge of this question was already introduced in [11635](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11635/texlipse-hotkeys-for-bold-italic-underlined).